# Two onchange events on dynamically created tags

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add the two events `onchange` for a tag (`<select>`) with two different functions.
Here is a part of the code:

```
        var slct=document.createElement("select"); 
        slct.id="tskSlk_"+idN;
        for (var i = 0; i < opt.length; i++) {
            var objOpt=document.createElement("option");
            objOpt.text=opt[i];
            slct.appendChild(objOpt);
        };
        slct.onchange=prcTypCh;
        slct.onchange=statBar;
        tsks.appendChild(slct);
```

So i have these two functions and want the two of them to be performed once someone select an option from the list. 
I know two possible ways:

1. make one of them to be `onblur`
2. make the second function to be called from the first.

The first is not working at all for me, and the second is good only for now. So is there any other way?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think this would answer your question :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411055/javascript-multiple-event-listeners-handlers-on-the-same-element

Comment: You'll have to use `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` (depending on your browser) to bind multiple event handlers.  Or, bind to a single function that calls the two other functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add both functions to the `onchange` event

```
slct.addEventListener('change', prcTypCh);
slct.addEventListener('change', statBar);
```

Or you could make your current `onchange` function just a handler that calls both functions

```
slct.onchange = myOnChangeHandler;

function myOnChangeHandler(){
    prcTypCh();
    statBar();
}
```

Also if possible to do in your situation I would recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or another [abstraction framework](http://javascriptlibraries.com/) to take some of the dirty work off your plate. That way you could do things like this:

```
$(slct).on("change", function(){
    prcTypCh();
    statBar();
});
```

Comment: the jQuery will work perfect for me, that was a smart workaround. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `addEventListener`:

```
slct.addEventListener('change', prcTypCh, false);
slct.addEventListener('change', statBar, false);
```

(As mentioned, you'll need to conditionally use `attachEvent` if you're targeting IE < 9. To this end, you should consider using a library like jQuery to cover the various browser implementations.)

Comment: Note this won't work in IE [prior to version 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener).