# Javascript more than 1 window.addeventlistener with "load" allowed?

Tags: javascript, events, load, listener

Is it allowed to have more than one `window.addEventlistener("load", function, false);`?

Like this:

```
window.addEventlistener("load", function1, false);    
window.addEventlistener("load", function2, false);
```

I know you don't have to, but is it wrong? Or is it allowed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - multiple event listeners/handlers on the same element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411055/javascript-multiple-event-listeners-handlers-on-the-same-element)

Comment: Thank you evan, really didnt see that post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. In fact, that's one of the biggest advantages of `addEventListener` versus a plain `window.onload = function...`.

Answer (score 2):

It is allowed that is the difference between `addEventListener` and `window.onload =`.

The first can have multiple listeners. The latter, only one.

Answer (score 0):

1. `window.addEventListener('load', function(){})` is **allowed for multiple times**
2. `window.onload` will overwrite all load listeners.
3. `window.addEventListener('load', function(){window.addEventListener('load', function(){})})` you should not use load event listener as IIFE, since than any more load listener you added nested-ly, will not execute.